# Why do languages like Java distinguish between string and char while others do not?

Tags: java, python, ruby, string, char

I've noticed that languages like Java have a char primitive and a string class. Other languages like Python and Ruby just have a string class. Those languages instead use a string of length 1 to represent a character.

I was wondering whether that distinction was because of historical reasons. I understand the language that directly influenced Java has a char type, but no strings. Strings are instead formed using char* or char[].

But I wasn't sure if there was an actual purpose for doing it that way. I'm also curious if one way has an advantage over another in certain situations.

**Why do languages like Java distinguish between the char primitive and the string class, while languages like Ruby and Python do not?**

Surely there must be some sort of design concern about it, be it convention, efficiency, clarity, ease of implementation, etc. Did the language designer really just pick a character representation out of a hat, so to speak?

Comment: Performance. Why have a separate `byte` type when you could just store an `int`?

Comment: also in the case of C++, for compatibility with C.

Comment: `char` is often a single byte (**often** *rolls eyes* - yes, I'm looking at you, Java). This does not always represent a readable character. Notice, on the other hand, that `string` in a class form is generally a collection of readable characters (doesn't have to be). But in any event, there is extra overhead to provide "string" functionality.

Comment: Why don't scripting languages increase performance this way?

Comment: @RageD Actually the decision of the Java designer is just consequent. They say a char is for characters not for storage of integer values. For that they introduced byte. This leads to a consequent separation between characters (where you possibly want to store unicode data) and integer values from -128 to 127. If they wouldn't have done that they would have had to introduce such a thing like wchar_t *urgs*. So it's more the other languages you have to look at ;-)

Comment: Because a string is an array of chars. If chars were also strings, then a string would be an array of strings, which doesn't exactly work...

Comment: @R.. My question wasn't what's the difference between a string and a character, my question was why don't scripting languages have a char class or primitive when C-based languages do.

Comment: Short answer: because *you don't need* a special type for strings. Fundamental types {int, float} suffice. (in C, a char is an integer type that large enough to express any needed character). Add all the sizes : {char, int, long, double}, maybe add unsigned types, Add {struct, union} (plus closure), add {array, pointer} (plus closure) and you are done. You just don't **need** a string type.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not asking about C, I'm asking about the difference between languages that already have strings. C-based languages also have a char type, and I'm wondering why scripting languages don't have them.

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by a "C based language". If you mean simply syntactically based (i.e. so called "curly brace languages", that might encompass compiled, VM and scripting languages, but other than syntactical similarity they are not necessarily architecturally similar.  C, C++ and Objective-C are directly related and are usually embodied in the same base compiler.

Comment: @Clifford By C-based I meant languages that were primarily influenced by C, e.g. Java. Those languages have a char type. But I've edited my question so that people don't think when I say C-based I mean C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 1** Added a number of links to sources; improved the historical story on Lisp; answered why Java has primatives.
**EDIT 2** Comment on modern scripting languages explaining how efficiency is no longer such a concern

Back in the old days, memory was expensive - even simple computers had only a few kilobytes. The typical terms of service you have to agree to would exceed the RAM of the whole system. This meant that data structures had to be *very* much smaller than those you can design today.

Computers started in Britain and the US in the 1940s and the minimum character set needed for those engineers was the Western European alphabet without any exciting accents. 0-9, A-Z and a-z is 62 characters. Add 31 control characters, space and some punctuation and you can fit all that into 7 bits. Perfect for a teletype.

Now, those 7 bits could be laid out differently on different architectures. If you used IBM, you had to know [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) which was completely different to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Languages of the '60s and '70s reflect these concerns, and packed strings into the smallest possible spaces:

- Pascal: A packed array of bytes - fixed length and not null-terminated
- C: Null-terminated sequence of bytes (often thought of as an array using the insanely hackerish idea that an array subscript is simply [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html))
- Fortran 66: Strings? You don't need them. Store a **pair** of characters in a **integer** and use READ, WRITE and FORMAT

As a programmer of these languages, I can say this sucked. Especially as most business programs required a lot of text entry and manipulation. As memory became cheaper, programmers tended to write string utilities before anything else to be able to do anything productive.

Fixed-length strings (eg Pascal) were efficient but awkward if you need to extend or contract them even a single character.

C's null-terminated approach has the disadvantage that the length is not stored with the string, so it is trivially easy to overwrite the buffer and crash the application. Such bugs are still a leading cause of computer insecurity. There are two ways of solving this:

- Check the string length every write: This is imply scan memory until you find the null character. Ugly
- `malloc` new memory and copy the string into the new memory, then `free`

Increasingly in the 80s standard libraries were brought in to handle strings - these were provided by the tools vendors and the OS providers. There were major moves to standardize, but the parties fought each other tooth and nail to control the standards, and it was ugly.

Increasing internationlization also brought another problem - international character sets. First, ASCII was expanded to 8 bits as [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for different European languages (accents, Greek, Cyrillic), and then [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) fully brought computers to all corners of the world. And that brought the issues of character encodings such as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and how to covert between these different approaches.

I should also note that [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) introduced garbage collection. This solves C's complexities with `malloc`/`free`. Lisp's incredibly powerful array and sequence libraries work naturally on strings.

The first major, popular language to bring these trends together was Java. It combined three improvements *in the language*:

1. Internationalization and Unicode: A distinct datatype, `Character` and the primitive `char`
2. Encapsulation: The issues with fixed-length vs. null-terminated were obviated by:

   1. Being immutable
   2. Clever optimizations in the VM and GC
3. Libraries: All basic string manipulation features were standardized in the language.

Nowadays there are languages where every value is an object. However when Java was conceived in the late '90s, GC and JIT/Hotspot technologies were nowhere near as fast as they are now (at least partially because of RAM limitations, but algorithms have improved too). [Gosling was concerned about performance](http://www.artima.com/intv/gosling313.html) and kept primitive datatypes.

One other point: In Java it is natural that there's a Character class - it is the natural home for a number of operations and utility methods such as `isWhiteSpace()` and `isLetter()`, the latter being somewhat complicated by Japanese, Korean and the Indian languages.

Python made a [poor early decision](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to define a character as 8-bit ASCII; you can see the consequent problems by first introducing another datatype (unicode) which is subtly different and incompatible, and is only now resolved by the complicated migration to Python 3.x.

Modern languages (including scripting languages) follow to the broad consensus on how a string library should look as exemplified by Java and Python.

Each language is designed for a specific purpose and therefore balances competing design concerns in different ways. Modern languages have the benefit of the enormous improvements in performance and memory in the last 60 years, so they can favor *generalization, purity and utility* over efficiency in CPU and RAM. This is explicitly true of scripting languages, which by the nature of scripting has already made that decision. Modern languages therefore tend to have only the high-level string type.

**TL/DR** Early computers were frighteningly limited in memory forcing the simplest implementations. Modern languages benefit from GCs recognize internationalization (8bit->16bit) characters and encapsulate string datatypes to make string manipulation safe and easy.

Answer (score 4):

Bottom line is that is just how the language designer decided to make it. It's hard to get too much further than that.

However, one point about C, which is generally considered a lower-level language in that the syntax more accurately reflects the nature of the data and tasks being performed. Treating a character as a string would be a level of abstraction that would be uncharacteristic of C. It would make it less clear what the data is like under the covers. And it would almost certainly add overhead when all you needed was a character.

Note that C-type languages do support single character strings, and so you really have the best of both worlds in my opinion.

Comment: I think it is rather "how it needed to be" and not an arbitrary design decision at all. A `char` is not merely a character representation despite its name. As a systems level language you need a type that can address individual memory locations.  What you might wonder is why there is not perhaps a `byte` type distinct from `char` as in C# or even `short short int`, but given the capabilities of early 70's computers that would have been an extravagance of redundancy.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest the decision was arbitrary. Only that that was the reason and we may not necessarily know what when into that decision.

Comment: That is true, the answers given, including mine can only be hypotheses and (perhaps educated) guesses.  In general C was written to enable the compiler to be as simple and lightweight as possible, and many aspects of its design show that.

Answer (score 2):

Now, my perceptions on the matter may mirror some of the answers on here in one form or the other, but I will say it anyway:

Yes, (like everyone else has mentioned) lower level languages like C take optimization, performance, and machine level details into account much more than scripting languages like Perl, Ruby, or Python. Now a consequence of this "full control" mentality, is that you generally have more things to worry about when compared to scripting languages.

So what am I trying to say? Well, a member of SO once passed me the "Zen of Python", and just a few extracts from that document contained some core Python philosophies such as "readability counts", "Simple is better than complex", and `"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` I emphasized that last extract for a reason.

Moving on, here is an example of an abstract programming language that **does** have a char type: SML. Take for example two statements I make in interactive mode:

```
- val a = "a"
val a = "a" : string    #interpreter type feedback

- val a = #"a"
val a = #"a" : char     #interpreter type feedback
```

In the above two examples, I had two ways to represent one human readable character, although they are fundamentally different types. Although SML is a relatively abstract language by today's standards, it's core philosophies lie in computation, mathematically expressive syntax, and bug safety. That last point is even more so the case for purely functional langues (SML is not pure). So while abstraction makes a point of stepping away from the dreaded details of lower level languages, it still does not place as heavy of an emphasis on concepts like "readability", and "ease of use" as does a language like Python.

In fact, scripting languages generally emphasize quick generation of code, and syntax that is easy to learn and use. As far as Ruby goes, Matsumoto himself even declared that the language should be 'fun to use.' Essentially, in my most humble estimation I think the reason for not distinguishing between a char and string datatype in languages like Python is encompassed by the concept of simplicity. Verbosity and convolution seems to be an enemy of scripting languages. Furthermore, as a last point, if one were so inclined to make use of C compatible datatypes, there is the `ctypes` library for Python.

Comment: Alas the question is closed, but I still think it's useful and your answer is great. If you don't mind, could you edit your answer to leave out the part at the end about the problems with C strings (null termination, memset, etc)? It doesn't necessarily apply to Java.

Comment: @Eva, Sure I can do that, Shortly after posting it I thought about that as well. Glad it was of use to you..

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't sure whether that distinction was because of historical
>   reasons (C only has chars, strings are formed with char* or char[]) or
>   if there was an actual purpose for doing it that way. I'm also curious
>   if one way has an advantage over another in certain situations.

In `C` the concept of a "string" is a character array/series of characters that is terminated by a ending character `\0`. Otherwise a "string" is like any other array in `C`.

In e.g. `C#` and several other languages the string is treated as an abstraction, a string is more like an opaque object. The object contains methods that work on the string but exactly how the string is stored is "hidden" to the programmer.

The reason for this is that C is a much older language and more close to hardware than newer languages.

How a string is defined in a language (whether single or dobuble quotes are used) is really just an implementation detail that the person(s) designing the langauge thought to be a good thing at the time.

Comment: Scripting languages are able to use single quotes for strings because they don't have a separate char type. I wasn't asking the difference between C and newer languages, I was asking the difference between C-based languages and scripting languages. I understand that a string object is an abstraction. What I don't understand is why scripting languages don't have a separate char type.

Comment: The manner in which C deals with strings is not so much to do with its age as its application.  You will always need a systems level language that can deal directly to the memory, register and hardware architecture, and C (and C++) provides that.  Few 'new' languages are "systems level" because C and C++ pretty much have it covered.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ a `char` is simply a "small" integer. While it is used as its name suggests for character encoding, its use for that is diminishing in the face of Unicode on desktop systems at least or any system that needs to support a variety of languages and alphabets.  However because these are "systems level" languages capable of directly accessing hardware, it is necessary also to have a data type that is capable of addressing the smallest addressable memory unit on a particular architecture; and that is why a `char` is necessary.

C# distinguishes between the type `char` used for character encoding (which is in fact 16 bit), and the smallest addressable unit type `byte` which is 8 bit.  That kind of clarity is the advantage perhaps from being later to the party.

C of course does not have a string data type at all in fact, it merely has a convention of a nul terminated character array and a library of functions that use that convention (it is incidentally a simple but inefficient convention as explained [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)).  In C++ the string class brings the advantages of a true string type and can avoid some of the inefficiencies and dangers - although mitigation of the dangers adds its own different performance hit).

Comment: What about scripting languages?

Comment: What about them?  The question is about C based languages and C is a compiled language.  Also my point was about C's requirement to be a systems level language - in making my point I may not have answered all your questions. Scripting languages are by definition not systems level - you cannot generally write an OS, bootloader or a device driver in a scripting language (or even a VM language for that matter) since they rely on a run-time environment that *is* the system. C on the other hand has minimal run-time requirements environment requirements, and is able to run "bare-metal" with no OS.

Comment: No, the question was about why C-based languages separate chars from strings while scripting languages do not. My question has nothing to do with the C language itself. Editing my question so it doesn't say C to end this confusion.

Comment: OK, then from my answer you might conclude that a non-systems level language dopes not need to deal with fundamental machine types but rather abstract types.